# Q: How to integrate Pyramid 1.5 and Socket.IO 1.3?

Tags: socket.io, pyramid, gunicorn

I'm facing a problem while using Pyramid Framework 1.5 and [Gevent-socketio](https://gevent-socketio.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) in the server-side and [Socket.IO V1.3](http://socket.io/) in the client side.
The problem I have is that when I am opening a socket in the client side the server throws Internal Server Error (500).
Also, the terminal outputs the following lines:

```
    socket = environ['socketio']
KeyError: 'socketio'
```

I've search about this problem and I read that it has something to do with the WSGI server I'm using (Which is currently Gunicorn. Maybe the way I am using it or set it up is wrong) but I couldn't find any good resource regard that issue.

I have few questions:

1. First, Is there any good integration between Pyramid and the new Socket.IO V1.3 (The gevent-socketio project haven't updated in the last 1 year and since then Socket.IO V1 published with major changes).
2. I read that I have to set up Gunicorn with Gevent or something but I couldn't do so. Any good resource or explanation about that?
3. Last but not least, off topic, when in production, how do people run their app? Using the terminal in the server? It sounds somewhat weird. Could someone explain how I should run the app in the right way using Gunicorn and Pyramid when in production (and not)? What file should I run and how? What it should contain?

Thanks!

UPDATE:
Maybe I wasn't clear enough but when I am using older releases (For example, Socket.IO V0.9.6) the problem doesn't occur. but when I am changing the JavaScript file from Socket.io version 0.9.6 to Socket.IO version 1 (and above) the problem shows up.

Comment: Please guys some help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The integration of Pyramid and Socket.IO has already been done for you:
https://github.com/abourget/gevent-socketio

2) You can see the Gunicorn documtention for information on setting it up, including what to put in Pyramid's development.ini/production.ini files (Paster):
http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/develop/configure.html#paster-applications
Additional reading: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-python-wsgi-apps-using-gunicorn-http-server-behind-nginx#serving-python-web-applications-with-gunicorn

3) Here is information about deploying your web app for production (Nginx is a very popular alternative to Apache):
http://pyramid-cookbook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/deployment/nginx.html

Comment: First of all, thank you very much!
Secondly, the gevent-socketio (as I mentioned above) haven't updated in the last 1 year and since then Socket.IO V1 published with major changes (which causes the problem. If I am using Socket.IO v 0.9 the problem doesn't occur).
So I believe that gevent-socketio is somewhat outdated and couldn't deal with the new releases.

Comment: That's correct, gevent-socketio currently doesn't work with Socket.IO v1, it works with v0.9: https://github.com/abourget/gevent-socketio/issues/192 ...but unless you need specific features of v1, gevent-socketio is currently the only option I know of. Waiting for gevent-socketio to work with Socket.IO v1 will probably take a long time, so if Socket.IO is important to you, I'd say move forward with gevent-socketio and Socket.IO v0.9.

Comment: I agree, Thank you Raj! I don't really need a specific feature of socket.io V1 but I saw that they improved it and added alot of things (such as the mechanism of engine.io that joined in). After all I think that I will stick with Socket.IO v0.9 if there is no alternative.